# Running total count with group by; SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I want to group it by year and create a running total of number of empolyees in every year:

```
2001   1
2002   8
2003   12
```

I got to the part of grouping and counting in every year, however I don't know how to create running total with it. Tried adding over() etc, but I still have errors.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM HIRE_DATE) "Year",
  COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) 
  FROM hr.Employees
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM HIRE_DATE)
  ORDER BY "Year" DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM HIRE_DATE) "Year", COUNT(*),
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(HIRE_DATE)) as running_count
FROM hr.Employees
GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM HIRE_DATE)
ORDER BY "Year" DESC;
```